# Why is the Bulma left margin (padding ) not displaying correctly

Tags: css, bulma

I have constructed a very simple BULMA CSS page however the left margin on the first column will not display i.e. the text is hard up against the left hand side of the screen.  Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Test page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.3/css/bulma.min.css">

</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar has-shadow is-white">
    <div class="navbar-brand">
        <a class="navbar-item">
            <img src="images/dfs.jpg" alt="site logo" style="max-height: 40px" class="py-2 px-2">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-menu" id="nav-links">
        <div class="navbar-end">
            <a class="navbar-item">Sign in</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="columns">

    <div class="column is-2">

        <p class="menu-label">
            Warehouse
        </p>

        <ul class="menu-list">
            <li><a>Receive Freight</a></li>
            <li><a>Customers</a></li>
        </ul>

        <p class="menu-label">
            Settings
        </p>

        <ul class="menu-list">
            <li><a>System settings</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="column is-10">
        main screen
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see any [margin classes](https://bulma.io/documentation/helpers/spacing-helpers/) in your code. What exactly are you trying to achieve? It won't do the spacing by itself.

Comment: Sorry, it is now displaying correctly... must have been a chache issue with old code.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your site content in `<section class="section"></section>`. From the Bulma docs:

> "Section components are simple layout elements with responsive
> padding. They are best used as direct children of body."

**Full example:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Test page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.3/css/bulma.min.css">

</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar has-shadow is-white">
    <div class="navbar-brand">
      <a class="navbar-item">
        <img src="images/dfs.jpg" alt="site logo" style="max-height: 40px" class="py-2 px-2">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-menu" id="nav-links">
      <div class="navbar-end">
        <a class="navbar-item">Sign in</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <section class="section">
    <div class="columns">

      <div class="column is-2">

        <p class="menu-label">
          Warehouse
        </p>

        <ul class="menu-list">
          <li><a>Receive Freight</a></li>
          <li><a>Customers</a></li>
        </ul>

        <p class="menu-label">
          Settings
        </p>

        <ul class="menu-list">
          <li><a>System settings</a></li>
        </ul>

      </div>

      <div class="column is-10">
        main screen
      </div>

    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```